# Почему Gson парсит объекты не по порядку?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Есть два класса:

```
public class RegisteredUser {

@Expose
@SerializedName("phoneNumber")
private String phoneNumber;

@Expose
@SerializedName("firebase")
private Firebase firebase;

public RegisteredUser(String phoneNumber, Firebase firebase) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.firebase = firebase;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public Firebase getFirebase() {
    return firebase;
}

public static class Firebase {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("uid")
    private String uid;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("provoiderId")
    private String providerId;

    public Firebase(String uid, String providerId) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.providerId = providerId;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public String getProviderId() {
        return providerId;
    }
}
```

И код, который парсит все это в json

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        gson.toJson(mRegisteredUser);
```

По идеи код должен выводить результат:

```
{
  "phoneNumber": "+380000000000",
  "firebase": {
    "provoiderId": "000",
    "uid": "00000"
  }
}
```

Но выводит:

```
{
  "firebase": {
    "provoiderId": "000",
    "uid": "00000"
  },
  "phoneNumber": "+380000000000"
}
```

Почему не парсит в том порядке, который я задаю в классе? И как исправить?

Comment: А Вам не всё ли равно как оно там полетит в пакете данных? Вы же не будете показывать юзеру сырой json. Порядок не гарантируется - ибо никак не влияет на работу приложений. И ещё - Вы вообще уверены, что `Gson` так сериализует, а не вьювер, которым Вы смотрите, так его показывает?

Comment: Порядок вывода, не указан, поэтому выводит ы произвольном порядке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для JSON формата порядок не важен, поэтому GSON не гарантирует что порядок объектов в строке JSON будет таким же, как порядок полей в Java классе.
Если Вам, все же необходимо, записывать в определенном порядке, то вы можете написать свой адаптер - https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization

Answer (score 1):

GSon не поддерживает порядок парсинга/следования полей (а иногда правда хочется).

Уже давно [висит issue](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/131), но разработчики прохладно игнорят его отсылая к кастомному адаптеру:

> Custom type adapters exist to handle this

В то же время [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) - поддерживает через аннотацию `@JsonPropertyOrder` можно явно задавать порядок полей